# Running python executable on a target machine

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

> Is it possible to run my python executable on target machine without the dll's?

I have used **pyinstaller** and it runs perfectly fine on a target machine but the problem with using **pyinstaller** is the size of the folder that it creates. My script uses the **selenium webdriver.**

> Is it possible to create an extension and run it from the browser itself without the client having to download it?

**if its possible then i need some hint**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I am fairly new to this site. I have edited my question, Could you please take a look at it now.